# change listener error javafx

Tags: javafx, changelistener

Please help! I have created a tableview with javafx FXML and populated it. I've also written a code to be able to fetch the value of the selected row to another FXML file. The problem is when I select any row it only fetches the Value of the first row of the table view for every row I select. Here is the code below that populate the tableview and for the row selection.

```
    public class ViewController implements Intializable{
    @FXML private TableView<Employee,String>viewEmployee;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Employee,String>staff;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Employee,String>sur;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Employee,String>first;
    observableList<Employee>data =FXCollections.observablArrayList();
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location,ResourceBundle resources){
    try{
       Class.forName("org.apache.deby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
       conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employee");
       String rest="select * from Employee";
       pstmt=conn,prepareStatement(rest);
       rs=pstmt.executeQuery();

       while(rs.next()){
             data.add(new Employee(
                    rs.getString("staffid"),
                    rs.getString("surname"),
                    rs.getString("firstname"),
                    ));

    staff.setcellValueFactory(newPropertyValueFactory<>("StaffId"));

    viewEmployee.setItems(data);
    viewEmployee.getSelectedModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new   ChangeListener<Employee>(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<?extends employee> observable,Employee   oldValue, Employee newValue){
    if (newValue !=null){
    try{
    Stage stage =new stage();
    Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClaa().getResource("Staff.fxml")
    Scene scene =new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}catch(IOException ex){
}
}
}
});

}
}catch (ClassNotFoundException |SQLException ex{

}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post working code? What is: "TableView<Employee,String>viewEmployee;", what is "Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClaa().getResource("Staff.fxml")"?

Comment: Actually the selection handling is correct, but still you don't do anything with the selection itself.